# How to resize image in primeng while maintaining aspect ratio

Tags: css, angular, primeng

I'm trying to use primeng p-image component to display an image. I'd like the p-image component to be a fixed width and height and the image to resize accordingly so that it maintains its aspect ratio.

Here is my current code:

```
<p-image [src]="photo.img" [preview]="true" alt="Image" width="250" height="250" 
    styleClass="square-img">
    <ng-template pTemplate="indicator">
       <i class="pi pi-check"></i>
    </ng-template>
</p-image>
```

I've added the styleClass square-img.

Here is my class:

[image]

As you can see in the browser, the style is being picked up but the image is stretched out.

[image]

And the class is being picked up:

[image]